# Ensime doesn't work with sbt + android-plugin

Tags: android, scala, emacs, sbt, ensime

i created a project by using this: https://github.com/gseitz/android-sbt-project.g8

When i start ensime in emacs to edit src/main/scala/Activity.scala i have red highlights almost everywhere. First highlight says by exemple in "import *root*.android.whatever" that android is not a member of *root*. But in sbt everything compile fine. How can i set ensime to work correctly with sbt + android-plugin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let Ensime know where it can find the `android` packages.  Add a line to your .ensime file that contains the path to `android.jar`, for example:

`:compile-jars (" [...] /local/share/java/android-sdk-mac_x86/platforms/android-10/android.jar")`

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer no longer works with newer versions of ensime. The new version requires something like

```
:compile-deps ("/home/aij/android/sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar" ...)
```

Here's a one-liner to edit the file for you, assuming $ANDROID_HOME is set:

```
sed -i~ 's|:compile-deps (|:compile-deps ("'"$ANDROID_HOME"'/platforms/android-21/android.jar" |' .ensime
```

Anyway, this is still just a kludgy hack to get it to work. The proper fix would be to fix one of the two plugins.