# sublime-ensime for scala not finding android packages

Tags: android, scala, sbt, sublimetext2, ensime

Ensime is not finding the android packages and gives errors such as:

```
object android is not a member of package <root>
```

I'm using sbt and sublime-ensime on OS X with Java 1.6 to try out a simple android demo project. I'm aware of some similar issues [for example this](https://github.com/aemoncannon/ensime/issues/41) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449175/ensime-doesnt-work-with-sbt-android-plugin),  but the solutions for those haven't worked for me.

The project was created from the template like so:

```
g8 jberkel/android-app
```

I have generated the .ensime file (below) using

```
ensime generate
```

Despite all the project dependencies apparently being listed, ensime still cannot find the android classes. However, sbt compiles the project with no problems.

Here is the somewhat lengthy .ensime file - I have also tried stripping this down to the basics, but with no success.

```
(:subprojects
((:runtime-deps
("/usr/local/android-sdk/platforms/android-14/android.jar"
"/Users/george/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-library.jar"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/classes"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/classes")
:module-name
"android-essentials"
:compile-deps
("/usr/local/android-sdk/platforms/android-14/android.jar"
"/Users/george/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-library.jar")
:version
"0.1"
:test-target
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/test-classes"
:name
"Android Essentials"
:depends-on-modules
()
:package
"android-essentials"
:target
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/classes"
:source-roots
("/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/src/main/scala"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/src/main/java"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/java"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/scala"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/src/test/scala"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/src/test/java"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/test")
:test-deps
("/usr/local/android-sdk/platforms/android-14/android.jar"
"/Users/george/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-library.jar"
"/Users/george/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.10.0-RC5/jars/scalatest_2.10.0-RC5-2.0.M5-B1.jar"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/classes"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/test-classes"))
(:runtime-deps
("/usr/local/android-sdk/platforms/android-14/android.jar"
"/Users/george/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-library.jar"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/target/scala-2.10/classes"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/classes"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/target/scala-2.10/classes")
:module-name
"android-essentials-tests"
:compile-deps
("/usr/local/android-sdk/platforms/android-14/android.jar"
"/Users/george/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-library.jar"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/classes")
:version
"0.1"
:test-target
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/target/scala-2.10/test-classes"
:name
"Android Essentials Tests"
:depends-on-modules
("android-essentials")
:package
"android-essentials-tests"
:target
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/target/scala-2.10/classes"
:source-roots
("/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/src/main/scala"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/src/main/java"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/java"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/scala"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/src/test/scala"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/src/test/java"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/test")
:test-deps
("/usr/local/android-sdk/platforms/android-14/android.jar"
"/Users/george/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-library.jar"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/target/scala-2.10/classes"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/classes"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/target/scala-2.10/test-classes"))))
```

[Here is the relevant part of the ensime server.log](https://gist.github.com/41f8bba4c5f56bf94649)

Is there a problem with my configuration, or is there something wrong with Ensime / Sublime?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this problem is related to how ensime uses the .ensime file being generated by the sbt ensime-sbt-cmd plugin.

I worked around it by refactoring my .ensime file so that it doesn't have any sub-projects.

For example, my original .ensime file above now looks like this:

```
(:name
"Android Essentials"
:module-name
"android-essentials"
:version
"0.1"
:package
"droid.essentials"
:runtime-deps
("/usr/local/android-sdk/platforms/android-14/android.jar"
"/Users/george/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-library.jar"
"/Users/george/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-reflect.jar"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/classes"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/classes"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/target/scala-2.10/classes"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/target/scala-2.10/classes"
"/Users/george/.ivy2/cache/com.google.android/support-v4/jars/support-v4-r7.jar"
"/Users/george/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-json_2.10.0-RC5/jars/spray-json_2.10.0-RC5-1.2.3.jar")
:compile-deps
("/usr/local/android-sdk/platforms/android-14/android.jar"
"/Users/george/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-library.jar"
"/Users/george/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-reflect.jar"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/classes"
"/Users/george/.ivy2/cache/com.google.android/support-v4/jars/support-v4-r7.jar"
"/Users/george/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-json_2.10.0-RC5/jars/spray-json_2.10.0-RC5-1.2.3.jar")
:target
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/classes"
:test-target
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/test-classes"
:source-roots
("/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/src/main/scala"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/src/main/java"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/java"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/scala"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/src/test/scala"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/src/test/java"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/test"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/src/main/scala"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/src/main/java"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/java"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/scala"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/src/test/scala"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/src/test/java"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/test")
:test-deps
("/usr/local/android-sdk/platforms/android-14/android.jar"
"/Users/george/.ivy2/cache/com.google.android/support-v4/jars/support-v4-r7.jar"
"/Users/george/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-json_2.10.0-RC5/jars/spray-json_2.10.0-RC5-1.2.3.jar" 
"/Users/george/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-library.jar"
"/Users/george/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.0-RC2/lib/scala-reflect.jar"
"/Users/george/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.10.0-RC5/jars/scalatest_2.10.0-RC5-2.0.M5-B1.jar"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/classes"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/test-classes"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/target/scala-2.10/classes"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/target/scala-2.10/classes"
"/Users/george/Source/Projects/android-essentials/tests/target/scala-2.10/test-classes"))
```

This issue is being investigated further [here](https://github.com/sublimescala/sublime-ensime/issues/56).