# Ensime for .java files inside android project

Tags: java, android, emacs, sbt, ensime

I have a very basic question about enabling `ensime` in `.java` files inside android project (basically its what suppose to be enjine mode as I understood) from emacs.

So I added plugin `{ id 'org.ensime.gradle' version '0.2.8' }` inside my `build.gradle` in root of my android project, generated `.ensime` file in project root and after invoking `ensime` from inside emacs with `MainActivity.java` file opened - it started ensime server successfully, and changed `.java` file major mode to `ensime Disconnected`. But no matter what I do looks like I can not connect to running server.

A also tried to generate new android blank project from scratch with `sbt` and `sbt gen-android` and tried to run inside that project root folder `sbt ensimeConfig` and `sbt ensimeConfigProject` - no difference, `main.scala` after enabling `ensime-mode` in it works great, if I try to enable `ensime-mode` in some .java file from that project, like `MainActivityTest.java` - the same as described upper - disconnected and no ensime functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like I found answer - its basically duplication of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449175/ensime-doesnt-work-with-sbt-android-plugin). All what needed to do is to add `:compile-jars (" [...] /local/share/java/android-sdk-mac_x86/platforms/android-10/android.jar")` to `.ensime` file.